# PowerShell split method on string value

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to grab a value from a string within my PowerShell script.

The string can come like this:

`$TargetOU = "OU=Company Users,OU=Company,OU=Organisation Users,DC=domain,DC=local"`

or like this:

`$TargetOU = "OU=Company,OU=Organisation Users,DC=domain,DC=local"`

Using the following will return "Company" in the first example but "Company,OU" in the second. How Can I modify this to provide just "Company" in both instances?

```
$TargetOU.Split('= ')[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a `,` to the characters in your `split` method.
This is because you split your string at every char given to the `split` method.
Your first string splits to:

```
OU
Company
Users,OU
Company,OU
Organisation
Users,DC
domain,DC
local
```

while your second string splits to:

```
OU
Company,OU
Organisation
Users,DC
domain,DC
local
```

When using `$TargetOU.Split('= ,')` instead your second string will split to:

```
OU
Company
OU
Organisation
Users
DC
domain
DC
local
```

where the element with index 1 is only "Company", not "Company,OU"

Comment: Spot on thanks. I was reading it as start at "=" and finish at " " rather than splitting at all characters given. So simple and exactly what I was after. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Given your examples of input this returns "Company" every time.

What it does: saves your split in a variable and checks if that variable contains a comma, as it would if "OU=Company,OU=Organisation Users,DC=domain,DC=local" was your input. If true, split that again at the comma and save the first part in a variable. I used the same variable name as with the first split, since I assume you want to do the same thing with the result later in your script, regardless of how the input looks.

```
$SplitTargetOU = $TargetOU.Split('= ')[1]
if ($SplitTargetOU -like '*,*')
{
$SplitTargetOU = $SplitTargetOU.Split(',')[0]
}
```

EDIT: J. Bergmann's answer was a little simpler. Nice one. :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't work for me. The split method is not treating the characters as a character array. To fix it, I have to explicitly cast it:

```
"OU=Company Users,OU=Company,OU=Organisation Users,
 DC=domain,DC=local".Split('= ,')
```

returns

```
OU=Company Users,OU=Company,OU=Organisation Users,DC=domain,DC=local
```

but

```
"OU=Company Users,OU=Company,OU=Organisation Users, 
 DC=domain,DC=local".Split([char[]]'= ,')
```

returns

```
OU
Company
Users
OU
Company
OU
Organisation
Users
DC
domain
DC
local
```